# Data rebalancing in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite, gridgain

In Ignite with persistence enabled and all caches in replication mode, I added a new node to the topology. But the data distribution/rebalancing is not happening.

I opened visor and checked if the nodes entries are same but the new node entries are always zero.

What should I do such that the data is copied to the new node as soon as I connected?

Note: The cache rebalancing mode I used is default ASYNC ones.

Answer (score 2):

Please read about baseline topology:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/baseline-topology

You should add your new node to BT using a control tool or java code.